# NSJSONSerialization leaking - can't figure out why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

SO here is my method:

```
-(NSString *) getTemplateNamed: (NSString *) aTemplateName withManufacturerID: (NSNumber *) aManufacturerID withPriceLevel: (NSNumber *) aPriceLevel {
    @try {

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Manufacturer" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
        [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ManufacturerID==%@", aManufacturerID]];
        [request setFetchLimit:1];
        NSError *err=nil;
        NSArray *entities = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
        request=nil;

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[[entities lastObject] ManufacturerSettingsString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        NSString *akey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"PriceLevel%@", aPriceLevel ];
        if ([aPriceLevel isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {   akey=@"BasePrice"; }

        NSString *template = [dictionary valueForKey:aTemplateName];
        NSString *output = [template stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Price" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Formatted", akey]];

        return  output;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return @"";
    }
}
```

Here is the offending line according to Profiler:

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[[entities lastObject] ManufacturerSettingsString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

It looks like it is the NSJSONSerialization that causes the problem - any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean leaking? how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: running the leaks tool in Profiler, extended details for the leaks point directly to that line of code

Comment: Have you run the static analyzer?  Have you fixed all of its warnings?  How do you know the problem isn't in `[[entities lastObject] ManufacturerSettingsString]`?

Comment: The Leaks instrument tells you where the leaked object was allocated, and (if you have “Record reference counts” enabled) it can show you where the object was retained, released, and autoreleased.  But, by definition, a leaked object is missing at least one `release` or  `autorelease`.  The Leaks instrument can't show you where that missing `release` or `autorelease` is *supposed* to be.  It's up to you to figure that out.

Comment: I guess I do not know it that is the issue, running static analyzer shows me nothing wrong in the method though